# Selective Autorotation within a UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, rotation

Greetings! Here's the scenario.

Starting with a navigation controller (and no tab bar is present - it is hidden from a previous view controller push), I init a new view controller and push it onto the nav controller stack. This new VC contains a lonesome **UIView** into which I programmatically add a UIScrollView with the same frame. (I wanted to avoid the **UIView**, but this was the only way I could get **self.view** to be assigned to something. I suspect casting a **UIScrollView** to **UIView** in **viewDidLoad** is not advisable.)

So now we have a nav bar, and a scroll view. I've set it up to scroll through some images (big surprise, I know!), and that works just fine. Now I want this to support autorotation. So I respond in the VC like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Compile and run. Aaaand ... nothing. Obviously I've done something wrong.

Now, I've already read the post regarding [UINavigationController and autorotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970482/uinavigationcontroller-and-autorotation), and I get the sneaking suspicion that I'm going about this the wrong way, and making it way more complicated than necessary.

There's got to be a better way to present a **UIScrollView** that supports autorotation. Perhaps the Nav Controller is getting in the way, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Ideally, I'd like something without any kind of nav bar showing. Instead, we have a toolbar/status bar that appears/hides from the top (like you see when playing video). If the nav bar must remain - or if that's REALLY a shorter-height nav bar I'm seeing when playing video vs. a toolbar, however do I get the thing to rotate around? The thing is, I only want it to rotate in this particular mode, when viewing the pix. Not at any other time.

Dare I try using a modal VC? (Yeccch - no, that can't be right either. Plus it has a nav bar anyway.)

Comment: This thread might hold a clue (concerning the chain of VCs): http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1646143

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can solve this without subclassing by creating a UITabBarController category.

Here is the category implementation which handles my case where I have anonymous UINavigationControllers associated with my tabs and custom UIViewController subclasses as the root view controllers of the UINavigationControllers:

```
@implementation UITabBarController (Rotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{   
    if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UIViewController *rootController = [((UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        return [rootController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

I also have a category on UINavigationController which defaults to returning YES. So, the default behavior is to enable rotation and I can return NO from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation for just the controllers and orientations for which I wish to disable rotation.

Comment: Brilliant! Categories are so much cleaner, and the use of two in tandem is even sweeter.

Comment: Great, but i had a problem with any tabs that were navigation controllers, if they were inside the 'more' tab (our app has lots of tabs). My workaround is here: http://splinter.com.au/finding-the-currently-visible-view-in-a-uitab

Comment: i created the category on UITabBarController same as the answer and i also created a category for UINavigationController and return only YES, but i cant seem to make it work, sorry.. :/ how do you do it?

Answer (score 5):

Yep - it *was* easier than I thought!

True, no tab bar is visible ... but this is still, at the core, a tab bar-based app.

Unless the **UITabBarController** allows autorotation, all bets are off for any other views. So, it's simply a matter of subclassing **UITabBarController** and responding appropriately to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` (vs. making it part of the App Delegate as Xcode does by default).

How do you do that? Glad you asked. Follow these steps only if you've created a tab bar controller app using the Xcode defaults. (*BACKUP* your work before trying this! Disclaimer disclaimer, yadda yadda.)

1. Create a new **UIViewController** subclass (we'll call it VC). Adjust it to be a subclass of a **UITabBarController** with an explicit delegate of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.
2. Transplant all the Tab Bar delegate bits from your App Delegate into this new VC.
3. In your new VC's `viewDidLoad` method, add `self.delegate = self;` to the end.
4. In **MainWindow.xib** (or wherever your tab bar controller and tab bar are defined), pick your Tab Bar Controller object and go to the Identity Inspector (*Cmd-4*). Change the class to your new VC instead of the standard **UITabBarController** class.

Now we're in business. Just add this to the new VC source:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES; // Adjust to taste
}
```

Why the delegate stuff? The IB file's owner is **UIApplication**, and I couldn't tie the delegate to my new VC via IB. Since I want the chance to respond to delegate methods, I added it in explicitly. If you don't need that, it's OK to leave it out. (If this *can* be done in IB, someone please chime in!)

The only remaining trick is setting this to `YES` *selectively*. You may not want to support autorotation all of the time (as is my case). Here's how I do it. First, I change that newly-added method (from above) ... to this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
```

Now I can respond to this same method from any of my app's VCs, and it will bubble up to the Tab Bar controller! For instance, in my app, I have a VC that I only want to show in Portrait, so I respond like so:

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

However, this same VC can take the user to a photo gallery, for which I *do* want to allow some rotation. In that VC's autorotate method, I respond differently:

```
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
```

Now the gallery view will allow autorotation to all orientations except upside-down portrait, plus when I go back up the view controller chain, the orientation reverts to portrait. :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler still:

1) Subclass `UITabBarController` and implement the `shouldAutorotate`... as you described (second code snippet)

2) Change your `xxxAppDelegate.h` to have the class of the `UITabBarController` changed to the subclass you just created. (use #import YourNewTabBarController.h)

3) In `MainWindow.xib` change the class of the tab bar controller to your new class.

Presto!

PS: `YourNewTabBarController` should ONLY implement the `shouldAutoRotate`....
Remove all other (auto generated) stuff.