# UIWebView: Media Player Rotates View Controller

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rotation

I'm encountering an issue while using a webview. My app is currently a portrait application, but when a media player loads in a webview within my app, the user can rotate the player, which rotates my view controller as well. I know I can get a notification for when the player comes up and disappears, but is there a way to prevent it from rotating the controller in the first place?

It doesn't seem like anyone has an answer. I have all of the standard "don't rotate unless if I tell you to" methods and plist values, but its still rotating. Its only when I load up a webview and the media player loads over it. If I rotate my device, the media player rotates along with it, which feels natural, but when I go back to the webview view controller, its rotated, which isn't good.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. A video player in a web view does not autorotate when the view controller that owns the web view forbids rotation. Tested on 4.3, 5.1 and 6.0

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Have you tried loading up youTube with your device and make sure that your rotation lock is off?

Comment: I believe your bug is elsewhere. Here's a test project to confirm: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1296542/NoRot.zip

Comment: @RileyE is your application tab based?

Comment: No. Its UINavigationController based.

Comment: @Mashhadi would that cause an issue?

Comment: It is the issue. Why does it rotate when there is a navigation controller and when there isn't, it won't rotate?

Comment: It doesn't metter that you have a navigation controller. If your controller is in Tabbar then it may cause this issue.

Comment: It actually is also with a navigation controller. I've removed the controller and it prevented the issue. Its a stupid bug.

Comment: I think this works fine with YouTube videos but other video sources show the issue.

Comment: @nh32rg What do you mean? I'm just curious, since I've only tried it with YouTube (the media player loads within my app, through the web view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this key in your info.plist :

UISupportedInterfaceOrientations and set it to UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this a blind shot. I've used this trick to force the system to adjust to the required orientation, add this lines when the webview will appears, or when the player will disappear:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Try in some of those methods, or in the didAppear or didDisappear if dosen't work. I know it look like rubbish, but sometimes works.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I'm hoping to avoid unnecessary processing. I could probably just force it by manually changing the device orientation.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame, but this kind of stuff is the only solutions for orientation issues in iOS, I've struggled with this a lot.

Comment: But I'm sure that the is a solution. This is a very major issue!

Comment: Apple is too big of a corporation to have this large of a bug.

Comment: If you found it, let me know! As far as I know, there is no other way. (But, don't tell anybody - AKA NDA - they are completely changing the way orientations transitions works in iOS 6, so maybe there's your "solution")

Comment: This is the solution, check my answer in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970482/uinavigationcontroller-and-autorotation/5347071#5347071

Comment: @xingzhi.sg The question is about preventing rotation—not about how to fix it.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, unless we are Apple engineers. This is a known "bug" since iOS 3 at least and until Apple fix it we just try to live with it with our dirty fixes...

Comment: Is it just me, or is this ridiculous? How can there be this big of an issue for so long?